# React-Router getUserConfirmation functionality issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am trying to observe the React Router state change when user clicks browser back button.
My application has a redux Provider and Material-UI integrated. However I am not able to get `getUserConfirmation` working.

Please find below my code snippet.

```
 const getConfirmation = (message, callback) => {
      const allowTransition = window.confirm(message)
      strong textcallback(allowTransition)
    }
    const myHistory = createBrowserHistory();

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store} >
        <MuiThemeProvider>
           <BrowserRouter basename="/app" history={myHistory} getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation} >
              <App />
           </BrowserRouter>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Used Library Versions:

```
React v16
react-router-dom v4.2.2
react-redux v5.0.6
material-ui v0.20.0
redux v3.7.2
```

Some of the docs I referred:

```
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter
https://codepen.io/pshrmn/pen/MpOpEY
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRXzMg?editors=0010
```

Appreciate your help, Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Emm.. maybe you need   <Prompt /> Component as well , there is my demo 
 hope this is useful.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Prompt } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Row, Col, Modal } from 'antd';
import { Home, About, Topics } from './components';


const getConfirm = (content, callback) => {
    Modal.confirm({
        title: 'confirm',
        content,
        onOk: () => {
            callback(true);
        },
        onCancel: () => {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
};
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router getUserConfirmation={getConfirm}>
                <div className="App">
                    <Prompt message="Are you sure you want to leave?" />
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Link to="/with-state">withState</Link>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path="about" component={About} />
                    <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```